# Duplicate pipeline Run Ids in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I noticed 5 duplicate rows in my SQL database after running several Data factory pipelines. When troubleshooting I found out, what seems to be, two identical pipeline runs? Should these not be unique? Have I encountered a bug? If the pipeline was for some reason triggered twice for the same event these runs should have unique Run Ids, right?

[Pipeline runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQQP2.png)

Comment: When opening the Data factory in an incognicto window it seems I only get one of the runs, so this might be a browser-related caching issue. However, I still have some duplicate rows in my database that have been inserted with a duplicate Run Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I managed to solve it. The actual problem was on my part and not related to the question, but the duplicate pipeline runs confused me and led me in the wrong direction. I think it was a UI bug somehow related to the browsers cache.